# Can One Write Methods for Three Instances of Same Class

Tags: python, class, methods, self

I ask this question out of curiosity, there are probably many workarounds to what I am about to ask.

When you create a class in python, you can define methods that take two instances of this class, by the use of "self" and "other" keywords, such as

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.x + other.x
```

Can you do the same with 3 or more instances of the same class? That is, is there something like "self", "other", "another"?

Comment: You can write any such method you want, there's just no standard `__dunder__` method with that signature that would map to any operator (what would a three-operand operator even look like?). But `def my_method(self, other, another)` is perfectly valid…

Comment: `other` is not a keyword here - it's just an arbitrary identifier that someone chose to use as the name of that second parameter.  (`self` is actually the same, but there's a much stronger convention concerning its use as the first parameter to a method.)

Comment: I see, since my editor highlights `self` and `other`, I thought those were keywords. In case I need it, I will be using: `self`, `other`, `another`, `yetanother`. Sounds really sexy to my ear.

Comment: Consider `def foo(self, *args)`…

Comment: Even sexier! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list that contains the arguments of different class instances that can be called from a loop.

```py
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, others):
        temp = self.x
        for obj in others:
            temp += obj.x
        return temp
        
x = MyClass(5)
y = MyClass(5)
z = MyClass(5)

print(x.__add__([y, z])) # 15
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question, because the `others` in your code has to be an iterable, I want to specifically input `MyClass`, not a list of `MyClass`'es. Comments above cleared it out for me, though.